# Cant open webcam media device in modal window

Tags: javascript, webrtc, bootstrap-modal, webcam

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <!-- <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4> -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- <video autoplay id="video1" style="width: 100%; height: auto; margin:0 auto; frameborder:0;"> -->
          <!-- <source src="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4"> -->
          <div id="modal-body">
            <video autoplay="true" id="video1">
            
            </video>
          </div>
          <!-- Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video tag.
        </video> -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var video = document.querySelector("#video1");

      if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        console.log('getUserMedia supported.');
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
          .then(function (stream) {
            video.srcObject = stream;
          })
          .catch(function (err0r) {
            console.log("Something went wrong!");
          });
    } 
</script>
```

[image]

I am trying to make a modal window that pops up when a button is clicked. If I run standalone in a .html file this  snipped works, as soon as I add it into the modal window nothing displays and I see that error from the client connecting to this server. Sorry if this is a stupid mistake im not great with js.

The window pops up and displays grey screen where the video stream would go but the browser cant seem to find or properl gain access to the cam.

Comment: What browser are you trying this in? https://caniuse.com/?search=navigator.mediaDevices

Comment: firefox and brave the simple html file opens in both and streams webcam and audio

Comment: See the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Navigator/mediaDevices#specifications). `navigator.mediaDevices` requires a secure context, i.e. `HTTPS`.

Comment: oh that does make sense thank you ill check that out